# Solving inhomogeneous vector differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, vectors

I'm trying to solve:
$$\dot{y} = By + \begin{pmatrix}
-2t \\
1+3t
\end{pmatrix} $$
Where $B = \begin{pmatrix}
3 & 2 & \\
-5 & -3 &
\end{pmatrix}$
I'm also giving the information $y(0) = \begin{pmatrix}
0 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$

**My attempt:**

I tried finding the eigenvectors: $\lambda_1 = i$, $\lambda_2 = -i$.

With eigenvectors $v_1 = \begin{pmatrix}
(-3-i)/5 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$, $v_2 = \begin{pmatrix}
(-3+i)/5 \\
1
\end{pmatrix}$

Then i inserted in to the equation:
$$y = C_1 \exp{(t\lambda_1)}v_1 + C_2 \exp{(t\lambda_2)}v_2$$
but using the initial starting condition i am finding $C_1 $ and $C_2$ to equal $0$, and therefore $y$ = 0.

But this doesn't fufill the equation. I would love your input in what did i do wrong. I'm worried i'm not using the vector $\begin{pmatrix}
-2t \\
1+3t
\end{pmatrix}$

Comment: do you know how to solve ${\dot x}=b x +f(t)$ ?

Comment: I don't know - what is the equation called with the  $f(t)$ part ?

Comment: it is an *inhomogeneous* equation, and you solved the *homogeneous* one

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You solved the homogeneous equation $\dot{y} = By$ to get your solution $y$. Now you need to get a particular solution $y_p$, and the actual solution will be $y + y_p$, then you can plug in the initial condition.